# How do I reset and fix my path so that java and python can work again?

Tags: python, java, bash, path

My path is all messed up, javac and python commands not found, I even uninstalled and reinstalled java. I would throw in random stuff from the internet into my terminal whenever my code wouldn't work and have subsequently ruined my path, I've even added stuff to my bash_profile and I don't know how to reset it or fix it. very frustrated. sorry I'm a noob

echo $PATH gives this:

```
Khalids-MacBook-Air:~ khalidhamid$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

~/.bash_profile gives this:

```
Khalids-MacBook-Air:~ khalidhamid$ ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/khalidhamid/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

javac Student.java gives this:

```
Khalids-MacBook-Air:java khalidhamid$ javac Student.java
javac: file not found: Student.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: Your javac is working fine, you just didn't specify the path to `Student.java` correctly.  Try running `source ~/.bash_profile` to reset your path configuration.

Comment: @Andrew-Harelson Thank you for answering, I've tried that and I still get the same output when I run javac

Comment: Like I said, your javac is working fine, you just didn't specify the path to Student.java correctly. Read the error message, `javac: file not found: Student.java`. I can't tell you what to put exactly because I don't know where `Student.java` is located on your machine. You need to specify the precise location with a path. javac will not just search your entire machine for a file named `Student.java` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html

Comment: @Andrew-Harelson its located in documents/java, how do I specify that location with a path? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your javac, you just didn't specify the path to `Student.java` correctly. Based on what you've told me, `javac documents/java/Student.java` should work.

Comment: you're right It wasn't in my directory, added it now and it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Khalids-MacBook-Air:~ khalidhamid$ ~/.bash_profile
> -bash: /Users/khalidhamid/.bash_profile: Permission denied

That's normal. `.bash_profile` is a script, yes, but it doesn't have the execute bit set. That's good. It shouldn't. If for some reason you want to execute it:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Though, I have no idea why in the blazes you'd want to do that. It's already taken care of when you open a new terminal window (or a new tab in iTerm2.app or Terminal.app.

> echo $PATH gives this:

Well, java and python are both in `/usr/bin`, so you're fine. There's nothing wrong with your path. Macs ship with `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/java`, though they do not automatically lead to actual implementations: Those are wrapper executables that locate where you installed these things and then runs those. **There is nothing wrong with your path**.

> `javac: file not found: Student.java`

This is saying that `javac` was found and runs fine. `javac` then complains that `Student.java` doesn't exist.

You're simply in the wrong directory. Type `ls`, which shows the contents. You'll find no `Student.java` here. Go to the right directory first, or move `Student.java` to the right directory if you're already there, or create it if it does not exist.

> I would throw in random stuff from the internet into my terminal whenever my code wouldn't work

Yeah, don't do that.